# How to obtain an AnnexB H.265 codec string from the header?

Tags: encoding, decoding, codec, h.265, webcodecs

I want to configure a Web Codecs H.265 video decoder. To do that I need a codec string like: `hvc1.1.6.L63.00`, which should be obtainable from a header like:

```
0 0 0 1 
64 1 12 1 255 255 1 64 0 0 3 0 144 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 **63** 172 9 
0 0 0 1 
66 1 1 1 64 0 0 3 0 144 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 **63** 160 20 32 24 28 33 31 150 180 164 37 146 227 1 1 0 0 3 0 1 0 0 3 0 60 8 
0 0 0 1 
68 1 192 247 192 204 144
```

So far I was only able to figure out that these numbers 63 map onto the 4th field in the string and signify the level, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74098842/videodecoder-decode-output-not-called) answer for H.264.

Does anyone know how the other values map onto each other?